# How to capture a measure result at certain date?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have 3 measures`(Measure1, Measure2 & Measure3)` in my dataset. I have a "Sprint Begin" column in the dataset, what I wanted to do is `calculate "Measure1" on every Sprint Begin date and capture that result`. and `calculate "Measure2" only after 7 days of Sprint Begin date`, and `calculate Measure3 only after 14 days of Sprint Begin date`, each measure value should be captured for 14 days until the next Sprint Begin. I want to refresh each measure only every 14 days from the last refresh of each measure.

I want to calculate & refresh Measure1 when `Max(Sprint begin)=today()` only, else show the previous value( from last refresh)..Calculate and refresh measure2 when `Max(Sprint begin)+7=today()` only, else show the previous value( from last refresh)...calculate and refresh measure3 when `Max(Sprint begin)+13=today()` only, else show the previous value( from last refresh). those measures can be shown in a card visual.

```
Team    Sprint      Sprint Begin     Sprint End   

Team1    Sprint1    1/1/2021          1/15/2021                     

Team1    Sprint2    1/16/2021         1/30/2021                      

Team2    Sprint1    1/1/2021          1/15/2021                       

Team2    Sprint2    1/16/2021         1/30/2021
```

I was trying to store the measures in separate new tables using summarize(by Team & Sprint columns) and refresh them on those certain days manually but my source tables are big I could not even store them in separate tables because of memory issues. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to capture it? Maybe I don't get it, but it looks like you want to exclude in measures rows for Sprint in the future? If Today was "January 14, 2021", that you want to calculate measure1 only for Sprint1 and not including Sprint2 even if some data appeared.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. I want to exclude sprints in the future even if some data appeared. I would like to show zero for the future sprints.

Comment: Can you add sample data? Do you have relationship between SprintTable (where you have Start-End) and FactTable (where you calculate measures 1-3) ?

Answer (score -1):

you can create a master table for just storing the informations like
Sprint | Sprint Begin | spring end
this will help you to calculate in your measure by referring current date with the sprint begin and end date.